# How to test the changes done in app for iCloud sync before submitting to app store

Tags: ios, testing, icloud

I have one scenario where my app when downloaded from iCloud is not working on new iPhone device.
I have hypothetically thought of the condition and applied patch to make it work in this icloud sync condition.

But how I can confirm that my app will work perfect for iCloud issue before submitting?

Can we have a way to synch from iCloud the modified binary instead of the one we have published on app store.

I tried backing up modified binary on iCloud.
On restore it tried to restore the modified binary but it failed silently.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Pappu.. I'm facing the same problem now.. Have you got any solution for that?